# How do I get information (name) of the user who scan qr code with an android app that I build?

Tags: android, qr-code

I want to know how to get the name of the user who scan my QR Code.

I am currently building a system (android and web) that can record student engagement activities to events or programs organized by the university. An application such as **e-log** is developed and it has a scanner function. Students must log in and the app will have their details such as fullname, student id, faculty, year and so on. Students will scan the code using the e-log app and the scanned information will be stored in the database. So, my question is, how can Admin get details (name) about the person who scan the QR code?

I tried to google it but what I found was only people scan the QR code and info will pop-up. I want to know how to get the name of the user who scan the QR cod and view it on a web.

Answer (score 0):

With ML Kit's **barcode** scanning API, you can read data encoded using most standard barcode formats. Barcode scanning happens on the device, and doesn't require a network connection.

Barcodes are a convenient way to pass information from the real world to your app. In particular, when using 2D formats such as **QR** code, you can encode structured data such as contact information or WiFi network credentials. Because ML Kit can automatically recognize and parse this data, your app can respond intelligently when a user scans a barcode.

[link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/read-barcodes)